# How to pass value backwards or retrieve afterwards?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I simply want to display the count of rows. And I have read that it is bad practice to select data only to count rows. The issue I am experiencing, however, is that the HTML element in which I want to display the count precedes the actual count.

**Does anybody know how I can pass the count backwards or retrieve it once it is finished counting?**

```
<div>
  ...
  <div id="count-container">
    <?php echo $count; ?>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
...
<div id="data-container">
  <?php
    include "inc/connect.php";
    $stri  = "SELECT a, b, c, d... FROM table";
    $stat  = $conn->prepare($stri);
    $count = 0;
    if ($stat->execute()) {
      while ($row = $stat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $count += 1;
        echo '<div class="row">';
        foreach ($row as $key=>$value) {
          echo '<div class="' .$key. ' data">';
          if (empty($value)) echo "---";
          else echo $value;
          echo "</div>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
      }
    }
    $conn = null;
  ?>
</div>
```

**Is it even possible?**

Comment: Research MVC and see why they do what they do.  Usually it's a good idea to execute all of your business logic before you even get to your HTML.

Comment: i will. thanks for the suggestion. what do you mean by "usually it's CODE? idea to..."?

Comment: lol, typo sorry, meant good idea*.  Brain must have been elsewhere.

Comment: @Devon hahah ok now it makes sense. they kind of sound alike to be fair lol

Comment: Any framework, picked at random, will show you better ways of doing this. Anarchistic PHP code is a chaotic stew of CSS, HTML, JavaScript, SQL, PHP and sometimes other junk mixed in randomly. A framework splits this out into different *concerns* which makes it a lot easier to work with. Models deal with SQL. Views deal with HTML. Controllers interface models and views based on routes. They also make *functions* to encapsulate functionality rather than burying everything conditionally behind `if` statements.

Comment: @tadman your explanation of MVC makes more sense of it than what i had read about it prior, perhaps because i'm fairly new programming. i'm not huge into using frameworks. from the start, i would rather learn the nuts and bolts of and become comfortable with the bare languages themselves. any suggestions on good resources regarding MVC??

Comment: You'll learn a lot about programming in general no matter you start in the stack, so don't think you won't learn if you use a framework. If anything you'll learn more, you'll have better examples to work from and more code to examine for how they've implemented things. Have a look at various [development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) and find one that fits your style and needs. They come in a variety of forms, from thin like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to very comprehensive like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/).

Comment: @tadman i've actually heard about Laravel countless times before. you seem to be well informed, so i'll take your advice and give it a second looksy!

Comment: You may find Laravel is a bit strangling because of how specifically it dictates you do things, or you might find it's great that it's got your back no matter what the situation. PHP has an unusually large number of well-supported frameworks to choose from, so don't think it's a decision between Laravel or core PHP. Your problem domain might fit better with another one. This is a highly subjective call, like picking a car. Whatever you settle on, learn it inside and out and don't stop asking questions. That's how you'll constantly improve.

Comment: @tadman i guess it's similar to how some people might prefer loosely typed languages over strict languages or perhaps how one or the other might be more appropriate for a given situation. anyways, thanks for all of the info <333

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the output in a variable, and print it afterwards. That way you have the logic before the rendering.

```
<?php
    include "inc/connect.php";

    $output = '';
    $stri  = "SELECT a, b, c, d... FROM table";
    $stat  = $conn->prepare($stri);
    $count = 0;
    if ($stat->execute()) {
        while ($row = $stat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $count += 1;
            $output .= '<div class="row">';
            foreach ($row as $key=>$value) {
                $output .= '<div class="' .$key. ' data">';
                if (empty($value)) $output .="---";
                else echo $value;
                $output .= "</div>";
            }
            $output .= "</div>";
        }
    }
    $conn = null;
?>

<div>
    ...
    <div id="count-container">
        <?php echo $count; ?>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
...
<div id="data-container">
    <?php echo $output; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: interesting! concatenating the HTML wouldn't in some way mess with or mess up its format?

Comment: It will output the HTML without line breaks. If you want to have it pretty printed. You could add some `PHP_EOL`. ($output += "</div>" . PHP_EOL;)

Comment: Don't you mean `.=` for concatenating strings? `+=` will smash everything into numbers.

Comment: @tadman ahhhhhh no wonder lol. i'm kinda new to PHP, though not sure how i didn't notice that nonetheless

Comment: @Anthony Nothing wrong with being new. `+=` is just very confusing for someone who's used to JavaScript or other languages where that will add two strings together. PHP is unusually quirky as far as scripting languages go, it's highly influenced by Perl which is basically a fancy version of `sed` and `awk`, two tools even older and more low-level than Perl and PHP.

Comment: @tadman you hit the nail on the head. since `+=` is JS syntax, that's likely why i didn't notice it.

Comment: That’s what happens when you are answering questions at a late hour. My mistake, not yours.